# More than one value in select

Tags: select, knockout.js

I have a `select` field:

```
 <select id="feesSelect" data-bind="options: $root.fees(), optionsText: 'description', optionsValue: 'feesID', value: feeID(), optionsCaption: 'Choose Billing Type'"></select>
```

Is that possible to have more than one value in the `optionsText` attribute? something like this:

```
 <select id="feesSelect" data-bind="options: $root.fees(), optionsText: 'description' + 'status', optionsValue: 'feesID', value: feeID(), optionsCaption: 'Choose Billing Type'"></select>
```

I tried that but it is not working, I got an empty list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show multilpe text in OptionText with Knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442067/how-to-show-multilpe-text-in-optiontext-with-knockout-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a function:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.fees(), 
             optionsText: function(item) { return 'description' + 'status'}, 
             optionsValue: 'feesID', 
             value: feeID(), 
             optionsCaption: 'Choose Billing Type'">
</select>
```

That is:
  `optionsText: function(item) { return 'description' + 'status'}`

[Example from the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#example-4-drop-down-list-representing-arbitrary-javascript-objects-with-displayed-text-computed-as-a-function-of-the-represented-item)